# How to add and remove classes with selected options values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show only one div id **a** OR **b** as per selected value by jQuery/JavaScript, Like if selected value is s-license then div id **a** should be shown and **b** should be hidden and if selected value is e-license then **b** should be shown and **a** should be hidden, I hope you understand what I mean, Sorry my English is not good.

```
<select class="form-control" name="attribute_pa_license" id="uniqueid">
<option value="s-license" class="attached enabled">S License</option>
<option value="e-license" class="attached enabled">E License</option>
```

`<div id="a">Some Text</div>
<div id="b">Some Text</div>`

Comment: You can change your HTML structure a bit? At lease `id` for divs?

Comment: Where is your `javascript` **=>** Attempt(s)? StackoverFlow is not a free writing service. Please update your question to include the relevant source code/attempt(s)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a map of `option` values and `div`s and then hide-All and show selected on `change` event

```
var valDivMap = {
  "s-license" : "a",
  "e-license" : "b"
};
$("#uniqueid").change(function(){
   Object.values(valDivMap).forEach( s => $("#" + s).hide() )
   $("#" + valDivMap[$(this).val()]).show();
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var valDivMap = {
  "s-license" : "a",
  "e-license" : "b"
};
$("#uniqueid").change(function(){
   Object.values(valDivMap).forEach( s => $("#" + s).hide() )
   $("#" + valDivMap[$(this).val()]).show();
});
```

```css
#b {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="attribute_pa_license" id="uniqueid">
  <option value="s-license" class="attached enabled">S License</option>
  <option value="e-license" class="attached enabled">E License</option>
</select>
<div id="a">Some Text a</div>
<div id="b">Some Text b</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

***For better, approach*** You can use `data-attribute` to achieve it.

1.Add `data-value` attribute to your divs and add the corresponding value of select-box options.

2.Initially hide divs (`$('div').hide();`).(This will hide all div on the page so better to use a common class for divs and use that class to hide specific divs)

3.On select-box change compare the selected value with `data-value` of the corresponding div and show them.

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$('div').hide(); // initially hide divs
$('div[data-value='+ $('#uniqueid').val()+']').show(); // initially show the selected option corresponding div
$('#uniqueid').change(function(){ // on select-box change
  $('div').hide(); // first hide div
  $('div[data-value='+ $(this).val()+']').show(); // based on option value check which div data-value matched, just show that div only
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="attribute_pa_license" id="uniqueid">
<option value="s-license" class="attached enabled">S License</option>
<option value="e-license" class="attached enabled">E License</option>
</select>
<div data-value="s-license" id="a">Some Text</div><!-- add data attribute to div and give corresponding option values in it-->
<div data-value="e-license" id="b">Some Text2</div><!-- add data attribute to div and give corresponding option values in it-->
```

***Note:- if you cannot change your HTML a bit also then do like below:-***

```js
$('div').hide();
$('div').eq($('#uniqueid option:selected').index()).show();
$('#uniqueid').change(function(){
  $('div').hide();
  $('div').eq($('#uniqueid option:selected').index()).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="attribute_pa_license" id="uniqueid">
<option value="s-license" class="attached enabled">S License</option>
<option value="e-license" class="attached enabled">E License</option>
</select>
<div data-value="s-license" id="a">Some Text</div><!-- add data attribute to div and give corresponding option values in it-->
<div data-value="e-license" id="b">Some Text2</div><!-- add data attribute to div and give corresponding option values in it-->
```

Comment: `2.Initially hide divs` shouldn't that hide only those specific div's ? Like apply a class to them and hide that class? otherwise it will hide all the div's in the page

Comment: @JonesJosephI have added explanation regarding that. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

This would be a correct approach in case you want to add more options on the go.

You can add a 'data-target' on the options tags so as to specify which div to show when selected

```js
$(function(){
//Hide all the divs with a specific class
$('.showOnSelect').hide();
//Show the div corresponding to the selected option
$($('#uniqueid option:selected').data('target')).show();

$('#uniqueid').change(function(){
//Again do the same as above. This time use the option selected right now
$('.showOnSelect').hide();
$($(this).find('option:selected').data('target')).show();
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="attribute_pa_license" id="uniqueid">
<option value="s-license" data-target="#a" class="attached enabled">S License</option>
<option value="e-license" data-target="#b" class="attached enabled">E License</option>
<option value="s-license" data-target="#c" class="attached enabled">T License</option>
<option value="e-license" data-target="#d" class="attached enabled">Y License</option>
</select>
<div id="a" class="showOnSelect">Some Text a</div>
<div id="b" class="showOnSelect">Some Text b</div>
<div id="c" class="showOnSelect">Some Text c</div>
<div id="d" class="showOnSelect">Some Text d</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you meant something like this:

```
$("select[name='attribute_pa_license']").on('change', function(e){
    if(this.value == "s-license"){
        ("div#a").show();
        ("div#b").hide();
    } else {
        ("div#a").hide();
        ("div#b").show(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This should no doubt work for the source code given but what if the OP wants to add more options and divs.... I think a more dynamic approach would be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd update the markup a bit to help ease hide/show, such as

```
<div class="conditional s-license">Some Text</div>
<div class="conditional e-license">Some Text</div>
```

And in JS

```
$('#uniqueid').on('change', function(){
  const value = $(this).val();
  $('.conditional').hide();
  $('.'+value).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I went the same way as Alive To Die using data attributes, but using vanilla JS instead, and adding and removing classes to the element classLists.

1) Grab the `select`, and `divs` (I added a `div` class to the elements).

2) Add an `change` listener to the select.

3) In the `handleChange` function grab the value from the selected option, cycle through the divs removing the `show` class, and then add the `show` class to the div that has the matching data-value attribute as the option value.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div');

select.addEventListener('change', handleChange, false);

function handleChange(e) {
  const value = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
  divs.forEach(div => div.classList.remove('show'));
  document.querySelector(`.div[data-value=${value}]`).classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
.div {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="attribute_pa_license" id="uniqueid">
<option value="">---</option>
<option value="s-license" class="attached enabled">S License</option>
<option value="e-license" class="attached enabled">E License</option>
</select>

<div class="div" data-value="s-license">Some Text</div>
<div class="div" data-value="e-license">Some Other Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected option value in a select using .val() ex:

```
if($('.form-control').val()=='s-license')
    $('#a').addClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

For use a simple JavaScript approach without any dependencies

you try this function

```
function licenseFunction(element) {
let value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value,
    a = document.getElementById('a'),
    b = document.getElementById('b');
if(value === 's-license'){
  a.style.display = 'block';
  b.style.display = 'none';
} else {
  b.style.display = 'block';
  a.style.display = 'none';
} }
```

demo - [demo](https://codepen.io/zaheerahamd/pen/YLqVzw?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's Onchange event on dropdown & call a function into which you can write hide & show logic for div with corresponding ids using jquery.